Identifying a component on a motherboard marked "1R0 842 409"
Friend gave me a laptop that wont turn on, took it apart and found a busted component. I need help identifying and where to find a replacement.



It's marked:
1R0
842
409


It's no use trying to figure out what exact component the 1uH inductor is. Replacing it won't help. The Samsung memory IC is also chipped and the PCB is torn half with damaged traces at the letter Y of the word Battery. It needs a new motherboard. It's dead, Jim. As a component identification question to find the exact inductor, it's a good question, but it may have no answer. Asking where to buy a replacement or how to repair this is off-topic.
